# Как определить утечку памяти в Node.js Express

Tags: node.js, express

Поставил Node.js и Express.
Создал проект `$ express test-project` и запустил его `node ./bin/www`.
В итоге решил попробовать несколько раз обновить страницу F5, что привело к росту потребляемой оперативной памяти. Каким образом можно выявить утечку?

Comment: память растёт даже без express, создал простой сервер и провёл такие же операции: 
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(3000);

Answer (score 2):

Вам должен подойти модуль [memwatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memwatch). Он покажет не только утечки,но и места утечек.

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: ок,спасибо за изменения)